# Powershell Script Not Exiting Loop after Conditions are Met and Getting Caught on Failure Condition

Tags: java, powershell, automation

I'm working on a powershell script to stop and start a service on a remote server. If the restart operation fails, I want the script to send an email alert.

The scripts goals are to stop the service, sleep for a few seconds and then check the service. If the service is not running, try to start the service and sleep before checking again. Each time the script fails to start the service it +1 to the retrycount and the script will trigger a failure notification if the retry count exceeds the number of max retries. If the service is running, it should mark the restart operation as complete and exit the loop.

The problem I'm having is that when I run the script the first time, it enters the loop, checks the service and incorrectly marks it as complete. When I go to check the service after this, the service shows stopped. When I run the script the second time, it stops the service, enters the loop, attempts to restart the service, loops through this 3 times and then catches on the failure condition which is meant to trigger and email alert. It keeps on looping at the failure condition, dozens of times, until I force quit.

I've been scratching my head at this one all night and I can't figure out where I went wrong here. I'll post the script below:

```
$VerbosePreference = "continue"
$remoteServer = 'My-RemoteServer01' 
$serviceName = 'MSSQLServerOLAPService'
$service = Get-Service -name $ServiceName
$maxRetries = 2
$retryCount = 0
$restartComplete = $false

stop-service -name $serviceName
write-verbose 'Service Stopped - Sleep 15s'
start-sleep -s 15

write-verbose "Attempt to restart service '$retryCount' "

while ($restartComplete -eq $false){
     if ($service.status -eq 'Running')
        {
         $restartComplete = $true
         write-verbose "restart complete"
         }
         else {
               if ($retryCount -ge $maxRetries)   
                  { 
                   write-verbose "Service Restart Failed - Begin Alert"

                   $smtpServer = ('smtp.mymailserver.com', 00)
                   $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
                   $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
                   $dateString = get-date

                   $msg.From = 'no-reply@mymailserver.com'
                   $msg.To.Add('L3LYZA@mymailserver.com')
                   $msg.subject = 'URGENT ALERT - Service ' + $service + 'is' + $service.status + 'on' + $remoteServer + '.'
                   $msg.body = ([string]$dateString) + 'Service' + $service + 'is' + $service.status + 'on' + $remoteServer + '.'
                   $smtp.send($msg)

                   write-verbose "Alert Sent - Complete"
                   }
                  else {                 
                        if ($service.status -ne 'Running')   
                           { 
                            start-service -name $serviceName
                            write-verbose 'Service Restarting - Sleep 45s'
                            start-sleep -s 45
                            $retryCount++

                           }
                   }
           }
   }
```

EDIT: The solution ended up being changing the way I was checking the service status. I also added a throw in the failure condition.

```
$VerbosePreference = "continue"
$remoteServer = 'My-RemoteServer' 
$serviceName = 'MSSQLServerOLAPService'
$service = Get-Service -name $ServiceName
$maxRetries = 2
$retryCount = 0
$restartComplete = $false

stop-service -name $serviceName
write-verbose 'Service Stopped - Sleep 15s'
start-sleep -s 15

write-verbose "Attempt to restart service '$break' "

while ($restartComplete -eq $false){
     if ((Get-Service $serviceName).Status -eq 'Running')
        {
         $restartComplete = $true
         write-verbose "restart complete"
         }
         else {
               if ($retryCount -ge $maxRetries)   
                  { 
                   write-verbose "Service Restart Failed - Begin Alert"

                   $smtpServer = ('smtp.mymailserver.com', 00)
                   $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
                   $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
                   $dateString = get-date

                   $msg.From = 'noreply@mymailserver.com'
                   $msg.To.Add('L3LYZA@mymailserver.com')
                   $msg.subject = 'URGENT ALERT - Service ' + $service + 'is' + $service.status + 'on' + $remoteServer + '.'
                   $msg.body = ([string]$dateString) + 'Service' + $service + 'is' + $service.status + 'on' + $remoteServer + '.'
                   $smtp.send($msg)

                   write-verbose "Alert Sent - Complete"
                   Throw "service restart failed exit condition met"
                   }
                  else {                 
                        if ((Get-Service $serviceName).Status -ne 'Running')   
                           { 
                            start-service -name $serviceName
                            write-verbose 'Service Restarting - Sleep 45s'
                            start-sleep -s 45
                            $retryCount++

                           }
                    }
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the error, but found something that seemed to be an error.

You are checking the status of the service on line 3, but you are stopping the service on line 9. Then on line 16 you are checking if the status is running. You need to run Get-Service again to get an updated status of the service.

You can accomplish this with:
`(Get-Service $serviceName).Status`

My suggestion is the following:

```
$VerbosePreference = "continue"
$remoteServer = 'My-RemoteServer01' 
$serviceName = 'MSSQLServerOLAPService'
$service = Get-Service -name $ServiceName
$maxRetries = 2
$retryCount = 0
$restartComplete = $false

stop-service -name $serviceName
write-verbose 'Service Stopped - Sleep 15s'
start-sleep -s 15

write-verbose "Attempt to restart service '$retryCount' "

start-service -name $serviceName

while ($restartComplete -eq $false) {
    if ((Get-Service $serviceName).Status -eq 'Running') {
        $restartComplete = $true
        write-verbose "restart complete"
    }
    else {
        if ($retryCount -ge $maxRetries) { 
            write-verbose "Service Restart Failed - Begin Alert"
            $smtpServer = "smtp.mymailserver.com"
            $dateString = get-date
            $mailFrom = 'no-reply@mymailserver.com'
            $mailTo('L3LYZA@mymailserver.com')
            $mailSubject = 'URGENT ALERT - Service ' + $service + 'is' + $service.status + 'on' + $remoteServer + '.'
            $mailBody = ([string]$dateString) + 'Service' + $service + 'is' + $service.status + 'on' + $remoteServer + '.'
            Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpserver -From $mailFrom -To $mailTo -Subject $mailSubject -Body $mailBody 
            write-verbose "Alert Sent - Complete"
        }
        else {                 
            if ($service.status -ne 'Running') { 
                start-service -name $serviceName
                write-verbose 'Service Restarting - Sleep 45s'
                start-sleep -s 45
                # Get an updated status from the service:
                $service = Get-Service -name $ServiceName
                $retryCount++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, I changed mailing to the native Powershell Send-MailMessage. There might be a reason why you chose "Net.Mail.MailMessage", so do change it back if so.

Comment: I don't see what/ where you made changes. Are you saying to replace ($service.status -eq 'Running') with ((Get-Service $serviceName).Status -eq 'Running') ?

Comment: that seems to have fixed my issues. I also added a THROW in the failure condition after the alert is sent.

Comment: I saw that my script still had some errors, but that your revision seems to have fixed it. Good stuff!